# HttpUrlConnect not sending data to PhP

Tags: php, android

I am a starter in Android Programming and trying to learn by developing an app.
What i wish to do is send data to a webserver which will further process it accordingly. Now I earlier Used **HttpClient** function but seems to be deprecated. Some research took me to this **HttpUrlConnect** Class, it did not throw any error but didnt really work too! The data is not being received by PhP. Please help! Code is Below:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   SendData sendData = new SendData();
    Toast t4 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t4.show();
    sendData.execute("21.43","23.23");
}
class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // a-> Lat | b-> Lon
    try {
        String a_str = params[0];
        String b_str = params[1];
        String result = null;
        URL url = null;
        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("lon", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(a_str, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(b_str, "UTF-8");
            url = new URL("http://chalkbox.in/recieve.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "chalkbox.in");
            try {
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                Toast t0 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pushed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t0.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t1.show();
            }
            conn.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast t5 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t5.show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast t11 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t11.show();
    }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Now, it just toasts "Started" and and nothing then. I have checked the internet connection, permissions for internet access and everything. It Doesnt push data and doesnt toast any error either. eventually it stops working.

The PhP code is:

```
<?php
$long = $_POST['lon'];
$lati = $_POST['lat'];

$con = mysqli_connect($host",$user,$pass,$dB);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (long, lati) VALUES('$long', '$lati')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**LogCat:**

10-29 06:27:10.528    1919-1919/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

10-29 06:27:10.849    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

10-29 06:27:10.852    1919-1919/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb3ef0, tid 1919

10-29 06:27:10.876    1919-1927/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.031ms

10-29 06:27:10.890    1919-1919/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...

10-29 06:27:10.919    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ffd110, tid 1941

10-29 06:27:10.959    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4

10-29 06:27:11.009    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

10-29 06:27:11.036    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

10-29 06:27:11.036    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f1d580, error=EGL_SUCCESS

10-29 06:27:11.409    1919-1922/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 250.499ms

10-29 06:27:11.473    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

10-29 06:27:11.474    1919-1941/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3eabf80, error=EGL_SUCCESS

10-29 06:27:11.566    1919-1927/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2566(119KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1000KB/2024KB, paused 4.554ms total 147.763ms

10-29 06:27:11.588    1919-1927/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 11.688ms

10-29 06:27:11.669    1919-1919/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

**UPDATE:**

10-30 01:39:39.374  10716-10731/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2, PID: 10716
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)

```
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)

        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)

        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)

        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:344)

        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)

        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)

        at com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:39)

        at com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2.MainActivity$SendData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:80)

        at com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2.MainActivity$SendData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:42)

        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)

         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

at        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-30 01:39:43.082  10716-10731/com.employeetracker.theworkstation.attempt2 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 10716 SIG: 9

Comment: My 2 useless cents: in your URL (in your code), the path you access is "recieve.php", are you sure it's not "receive.php"?

Comment: Its always best to post the AndroidManifest.xml as well as the Logcat associated when checking for Android problems.... You might also post the access.log and error.log from the server (I am guessing apache, mysql, php) to make sure you had a correct transfer, and no server internal error. Finally, if your program uses internet transfer, but that aint part of the app core, I HIGLY suggest looking at [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have completely changed my answer, because the issue here is clear now. 
As I mentioned in the comments below, you cannot run a connection to the server on the main thread(meaning your activity or fragment currently running). 
What needs to be done is run it in an async class. Create a class as follows:

```
class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     try{
            //Your code 
            }
    return null;
}
}
```

Then you can call this class by creating an instance from it in your activity/fragment, and execute it.

You can find details on [this blog post](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/) on how to do it correctly

Comment: Apologies! That is a typo. and no I did not. I will do it and definitely let you know. Other than that is there anything else wrong with the code!?

Comment: can you toast something other than "pushed" in your catch? so we can know if an error is happening in android ?

Comment: Oh yes this is a main logical error, u will need to run the connection on anything but the main thread. I will post the code in about 20 mins fixing it for you

Comment: Thank You Soo Much! That is very great of you :D. As I am a learner and I am really keen to know what caused this and how did you fix it and what that fix does?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if you need any more help mate!

Comment: Thank You soo much! Just , How do I pass params to this? and should i just copy paste the code in sendData() in try {  } block? Also How do i access this code from an external block of code?

Comment: when you create the object from the class, you call object.execute(param1,param2), and in your try block you can catch those parameters using params[0], params[1]. To know where to place your code, check the blog post i talked about in my answer, everything is well explained there

Comment: Thank You soo much! You are amazing :D I'll let you know if it works and ping you again if i get stuck! Thank you soo much :D

Comment: No problem mate, Android is tricky to get used to but amazing once you get used to it. Don't forget to add a permission to connect to the internet in your manifest. (Also explained in the example i linked you to)

Comment: I implemented what you said. You can look at the updated code in the question now. 
Now, it just toasts "Started" and and nothing then. I have checked the internet connection, permissions for internet access and everything. It Doesnt push data and doesnt toast any error either. eventually it stops working. I'm sorry for troubling you again . :/ Please Help!

Comment: Its like the main thread crashes soon as I open the app. It just displays "Started" as I have it toasted in beginning and then it crashes. I guess there is some issue with the Async Class implementation. Can you please check this for me!

Comment: Can you post your logcat here?

Comment: I dont mean to sound stupid but I'm a newb soo I am not sure where to find the logcat in AndroidStudio! Can you tell me where that is?

Comment: When u run ur app, it's at the bottom of android studio and it shows the errors and logs of the app

Comment: I have updated the question! I have added the logCat at the end of it!

Comment: There's more to it, try to post the whole thing

Comment: No Thats it! if You want i can post the screen shot for you?

Comment: Send me your android project at: admin@ralphmelhem.com

Comment: Sent! Thank You! :D You're Great!

Comment: Yes i will take a look at it and explain ur mistakes here

Comment: the rar file is corrupted and didn't open. re-compress it and send it as a zip file pls, i'm on Mac

Comment: Sent! I'm waiting :D Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure it out ? Even I am working in it. no luck :(

Comment: It's morning here, i just woke up, I'll take a look in about an hour

Comment: oh! Okay. Sure! Meanwhile I'll also look into it.

Comment: Okay! So i finally got an error in my LogCat! I have updated the question and after the original Logcat Under "Update" heading in my question you can find the error that was displayed prior to app exiting! I hope this is of some help!

Comment: It's not crashing on my phone, But i have no way of telling if it's connecting correctly, try to return something in your php so we can catch that in Android

Comment: I have added the following in php: "PHP Says its Working!" If you read the value returned from php, you should receive this string!

Comment: That Crashing was due to Toast statements in Async Class. I read it somewhere. So I commented those before sending it to you. But it still crashes in emulator and doesn't send data :( ! I have been trying and reading past 24 hours without a break! Nothing works. :/

Comment: By the way that "PHP Says its Working!" is an echo statement.

Comment: I really hope you figure this out.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The log cats are showing error in Creation of Toast.
In best of my knowledge, you can't do UI operations on the main thread.
*For showing Toast in the async task*, you have to call **runOnUi** method.